# How to remove Custom GTM HTML Tags from DOM after firing?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

For single page applications I was wondering if it's possible to remove a custom gtm html tag from the DOM after it has been fired.
The idea behind this is to avoid an uncontrollable growing of the DOM through custom scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem in a recent project I've been working on. However, I haven't found any 'native' solution for it, mainly because every Tag that can be injected with GTM can inject code in a totally different way.

What I have ended doing for this project is implement a rather simple solution (even if not perfect), which consists in:

1. Include a unique ID for every "Custom Tag" in GTM, with a common prefix that can be stored inside a variable (SCRIPT_ID). A CSS class would be better, but GTM seems to ignore them at all.

```
<script id="{{SCRIPT_ID}}__PIXEL_ID">
    ... custom code ...
</script>
```

2. Create a function that searches and removes any script inside the `<body>` tag (where GTM injects the Tags) with an ID that starts with the previous prefix.

```
function flushScripts() {
    const pixels = document.body.querySelectorAll(':scope > script[id^="SCRIPT_ID"]');
    for (const p of pixels) { document.body.removeChild(p); }
}
```

3. Execute that function every time the route changes or every time you see fit.